# How to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{2^n - 1}{2^n} \right)^{\log_2 n}$

Tags: limits

I am trying to show that something occurs with high probability, and my final expression is
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(  \frac{2^n - 1}{2^n}  \right)^{\log_2 n}$$

Based on trying some very large numbers it seems that this does indeed converge to $1$, but how do I prove so rigorously? I don't know any good lower bounds for $2^n - 1$ when $n$ is large. I also tried L'Hopital's rule (using technology of course), but the derivatives are monstrous and don't seem to provide any clue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have $$\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}=1-\frac1{2^n}.$$

Comment: The limit is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\frac{2^n-1}{2^n})^{\log_2n}=(1-\frac{1}{2^n})^{\log_2n}=((1-\frac{1}{2^n})^{2^n})^{\frac{\log_2n}{2^n}}\to (\frac{1}{e})^0=1$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\Big(1-\frac{2^{-n}\log_2n}{\log_2n}\Big)^{\log_2n}=\Big(\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\Big)^{\log_2n}
$$

$c_n:=2^{-n}\log_2n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$, it follows that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(1-\frac{c_n}{\log_2n}\Big)^{\log_n}=e^{-\lim_nc_n}=e^0=1
$$

Here we are using a well know result that states that if $\beta_m\rightarrow\beta$, then
$$
\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\Big(1+\frac{\beta_m}{m}\Big)^m=e^\beta
$$
A nice proof of this can be found in Durret's book on Probability Theory on the section related to the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 2):

With asymptotics as $n\to\infty$,
$$\left(1-2^{-n}\right)^{\log_2 n}=\exp\left[\log_2(n)\log(1-2^{-n})\right]=\exp\left[\mathcal{O}(2^{-n}\log n)\right].$$
The last expression is just
$$1+\mathcal{O}(2^{-n}\log n),$$
implying that the limit is $1$.

Comment: How did you get that $\log_2 (1 - 2^{-n}) = O(2^{-n})$ when going from the second to third step? (It seems to me that this is necessary for the equality to be true.)

Comment: We know from Taylor expansion that $\log(1-x)=\mathcal{O}(x)$ as $x \to 0$ (here $\log x$ denotes the natural logarithm of $x$). We also know that $\log_2 x \propto \log x$ and $\mathcal{O}(Cg(x)) = \mathcal{O}(g(x))$. You should be able to show that from these results.

Answer (score 0):

Set $\log_2 n = t$, then $n = 2^t$. Get
$$
(1-\frac{1}{2^n})^{\log_2 n} = (1-2^{-2^t})^{t} = e^{t\log (1-2^{-2^t})} \approx e^{-\frac{t}{2^{2^t}}} \to 1
$$
The Taylor series expansion is due to the fact that $\log (1-x) \sim -x$, and $2^{-2^t} \to_t 0$